# cannot open file 'boost_python36-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib'

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm trying to use boost(1.68.0) / Python(3.6) on VS17. I've installed boost using `bjam.exe`. Is this error because of not using `b2.exe`?

My program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/python.hpp>


using namespace std;

char const* greet() {

return "hello";

}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext) {

using namespace boost::python;

def("greet", greet);

}
```

Include paths: `F:\C++ lib\boost_1_68_0;C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

Additional libraries paths`F:\C++ lib\boost_1_68_0\stage\lib;C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\libs;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`

I've already made sure `target machine` parameters are correct. 
Also, I couldn't find any library prefixed `boost_python` in `stage/lib`, all library name start with `libboost_`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it only takes a little trick to solve it.
1) Run `VS Command Prompt`, go to the boost root directory
2) Run `bootstrap.bat`

I think you have done these two steps, but the last step is slightly different:

3) Run `b2 stage link=static link=shared --with-python`

Then you can find `boost_python36....` in `stage/lib`